# Looping multiple lines of text with variables in bash

Tags: bash

I am attempting to grep all of the /home directory for certain words. If these words occur it writes a /var/logfile and then from there I would like this to be read line by line and then echo each line with information. This is what I have so far.

```
grep -r -i "word\|word\|word\|word\|word" /home >>/var/testlog

UNAME=`grep -r -i "word\|word\|word\|word\|word" /var/testlog | cut -f 3 -d "/"`
BLINE=`grep -r -i "word\|word\|word\|word\|word" /var/testlog | cut -f 2 -d ":"`
FILEP=`grep -r -i "word\|word\|word\|word\|word" /var/testlog | cut -f 1 -d ":"`

while [ "$UNAME" == "true" ] && [ "$BLINE" == "true" ] && [ "$FILEP" == "true" ];
do

echo "User is: $UNAME, The line flag with the word is: $BLINE, and the file path for the text is: $FILEP."

done
```

Comment: Are these matches supposed to occur on the same line? Sounds like a job for `awk`!

Comment: Good to know but what is the question?

Comment: The question I have is the /var/testlog ends up with multiple lines. I would like the loop to look at each line and provide the echo output and then return to line 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: please provide sample input, required output from that sample, what  you're getting now, and your thoughts about why it isn't work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

```
grep -r -i "word\|word\|word\|word\|word" /home >>/var/testlog
while IFS= read -r line
do
    [[ $line =~ (/home)/([^/]+)/([^:]*):(.*) ]] || echo Failed on line=$line
    echo "User is: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}, The line flag with the word is: ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}, and the file path for the text is: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}}/${BASH_REMATCH[3]}."
done <testlog
```

If the use of `sed` is allowed, then the `while` loop is unnecessary:

```
grep -r -i "word\|word\|word\|word\|word" /home >>/var/testlog
sed -r 's|(/home/(\w+)/[^:]*):(.*)|User is: \2, The line flag with the word is: \3, and the file path for the text is: \1.|' testlog
```